# how to redirect to a 403 errors page

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-403, cgi-bin

U have many 404 URLs in cgi-bin/ folder from 1 year ago;

But I don't redirect this page, because I'm using the following configuration:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ _main.php?url=$1 [L]
```

How can I get permission for control cgi-bin/* files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**after very tests ...**

i used this code **and worked ^_^**(i linked to my mvc "_main.php" and redirected with my mvc setting)

```
ErrorDocument 403 /_main.php
ErrorDocument 404 /_main.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this *before* the `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteFule ^cgi-bin/ / [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect any request for the cgi-bin folder to your homepage (`/`).